# Styling vaadin-input-container

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin22

How to styling new element in Vaadin Flow v.22 vaadin-input-container through common css?

```java
@CssImport(value = "./themes/mystyle/components/vaadin-input-container.css", themeFor = "vaadin-input-container")
```

and

```css
[part="input-field"] {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px var(--lumo-contrast-30pct);
  background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);
}
```

not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you reveal a bit more context? Which component you want to style? Are you in process of updating from Vaadin 21 -> 22? Have you checked https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/upgrading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vaadin-input-container` itself is `[part="input-field"]`, i.e. `[part="input-field"]` is not child of `vaadin-input-container`. Thus you need to use `:hos`t as selector.

```
:host {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px var(--lumo-contrast-30pct);
   background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tatu. I just wanted to create common rule for textfield, combobox, datepicker and etc. components.